# Создать Word/PDF файл с данными из Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть некоторый Word/PDF-шаблон, необходимо по кнопке в этот шаблон в определённые места вставить данные из базы данных. Затем либо создать этот файл на сервере и открыть в браузере с внесёнными данными, либо просто сразу скачать его. Как это делается?

Answer (score 0):

Из самого популярного можете использовать библиотеку http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Там же вообще с 0 создаётся PDF? Это же жесть наверное какая-то... Я вообще рассчитывал на то, что будет уже готовый Word/PDF файл с полями, куда типо пишется текст, т. е. "Имя: _________" и вот сюда просто сделать селект из бд.

Comment: тогда нужно подготовить word шаблон и сохранить как xml файл, а потом из PHP делайте что хотите

Answer (score 0):

для PHP есть FPDF, генерите с его помощью PDF с инфой из базы и выводите его в браузер либо скачиваете.
Для шаблонов есть дизайнер: https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/fpdf-designer-wysiwyg-script-generator/full_screen_preview/22704900?_ga=2.26196221.1375420612.1589042643-25791993.1589042643